# Restoring previous "Save Selection As..." behavior

Tags: front-end, save, dialog-window

I've just upgraded to Mathematica version 11.3 (from 8.0) under MacOS 10.11.5. I noticed that when I "Save Selection As..." or "Save Graphic As...", the pre-filled name is "Untitled" plus the appropriate extension. It used to be the name of the current notebook file plus the appropriate extension. I looked through the Options Inspector, but couldn't find an option that might produce the previous behavior, which I preferred.

Furthermore, I believe that the directory was pre-set to the directory containing the current notebook file.  Now the last directory used is selected.

Is there a way to get the previous behavior back?

---

**From Chat**

In chat, it was asked if "Untitled" appeared anywhere in the output of `Options[$FrontEnd]`. It did not.

Comment: I'm running V11.3 under MacOS 10.13.4 and don't get the "Untitled" default file name behavior you described. I get the current notebooks file name as I have with previous versions.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I am running MacOS 10.11.5. I wonder if Mathematica 11.3 is using a feature that exists in High Sierra that is not in El Capitan to determine the default filename for "Save Selection As..." and "Save Graphic As..."

Comment: Only Wolfram Research  can address the issue you bring up in your comment.